# Web Host for ASP.NET MVC Web Site

Tags: web-hosting, webserver, asp.net-mvc, sql-server

I currently host a ASP.NET MVC site on Microsoft Azure. It's a great service, but a little pricey. Costs like $0.12 an hour just to have your site live, and then they also charge SQL Transfer and storage fees. Not CRAZY expensive, but like basically $100/month even if the site isn't doing anything.

I wanted to find a web host for an ASP.NET MVC site, that isn't going to break the bank while it's in its growing phase. Only data we really need is for storing user accounts for sign-up/logins, and for hosting images. I know a lot of hosts serve PHP/MySQL, and there's also plenty that serve ASP.NET Web Forms, but not nearly as many that serve ASP.NET MVC/SQL Server.

You guys know of any that suit these conditions and are pretty easy to setup?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Microsoft site page lets you search for hosting providers](http://www.microsoft.com/web/Hosting/Home) based on parameters like type of server (shared, dedicated, virtual server) cost, technologies supported, storage, number of SQL Databases, number of e-mail accounts, bandwidth per month, support, uptime