# Looking for recommendations for Windows Web hosting companies

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, webserver, shared-hosting, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I've always used Linux web hosting companies such as Dreamhost and Media Temple. I have been asked to host a website that has .asp based files.

Does anyone have any recommendations for a Windows web hosting company that include but are not limited to:

- reliable
- good support
- quality reputation
- reasonable price

Comment: Does this help? - http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18964/web-host-for-asp-net-mvc-web-site/18983#18983

Comment: You may want to edit your question to specify ASP or ASP.NET and, if ASP.NET, what .NET Framework and features are needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most famous hosting company heavily focused on Windows (as far as I know) is Godaddy. Their main site is also hosted in Windows (only 1% of websites are using Windows). They have all the requirements you listed.